# iOS Local Notification, changing Close button text

Tags: ios

I'm using phonegap to generate a local notification. I would like to change the text of the Close button.

So, is it possible to change the text in the Close button of a Notification message?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to change the text in the buttons of an notification. All notifications appear the same for all users.

As you can see in the documentation in UILocalNotification http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html